# How to add into PHP ActiveRecord has_many association?

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

When using [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) and you have models like:

```
class Message extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array("user")
    );
}

class User extends ActiveRecord\Model {    
    static $has_one = array(
        array("message")
    );    
}
```

You can then add to association with something like:

```
$message = $user->create_message();
```

How ever when you have `has_many` relationship:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model {    
    static $has_many = array(
        array("messages")
    );    
}
```

previous does not work. Only working way I can find to add to association is the following:

```
$message = new Message();
$message->user_id = $user->id;
$message->save();
```

This feels like like an ugly kludge to me. I would expect something like following to work:

```
$message = new Message();
$message->user = $user;
$message->save();
```

or:

```
$message = new Message();
$user->messages[] = $message;
$user->save();
```

Neither of these work. What is the proper way to add to `has_many` association with PHP ActiveRecord?

Comment: The *proper* way would be not to add this at all. Active Record is not for ORM. It's purpose is to represent one row from a database table and intermingle it with business logic. Any AR implementation tucking an ORM on AR is broken by default. If you need an ORM, pick one that uses DataMapper, like Doctrine 2.

Comment: Explain "does not work". What kind of errors are you getting?